# Testing the type of a DOM element in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

Is there a way to test the type of an element in JavaScript?

The answer may or may not require the prototype library, however the following setup does make use of the library.

```
function(event) {
  var element = event.element();
  // if the element is an anchor
  ...
  // if the element is a td
  ...
}
```

Comment: you are not asking for the Type. the type is probably an Object. What you ask for is the tag, as mentioned in the answers, the `tagName` property

Answer (score 136, accepted):

You can use `typeof(N)` to get the actual object type, but what you want to do is check the tag, not the type of the DOM element.

In that case, use the `elem.tagName` or `elem.nodeName` property.

if you want to get really creative, you can use a dictionary of tagnames and anonymous closures instead if a switch or if/else.

Answer (score 77):

```
if (element.nodeName == "A") {
 ...
} else if (element.nodeName == "TD") {
 ...
}
```

Comment: Sometimes it is. Anyway, you could always use `element.nodeName.match(/\bTBODY\b/i)` or `element.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'tbody'` etc.

Comment: @Robusto is incorrect.  If the document is HTML and the DOM implementation is correct, it will always be uppercase.  According to:
http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-104682815 under the "tagName" section (for elements nodeName == tagName) "The HTML DOM returns the tagName of an HTML element in the canonical uppercase form, regardless of the case in the source HTML document."

Answer (score 21):

Perhaps you'll have to check the nodetype too:

```
if(element.nodeType == 1){//element of type html-object/tag
  if(element.tagName=="a"){
    //this is an a-element
  }
  if(element.tagName=="div"){
    //this is a div-element
  }
}
```

Edit: Corrected the nodeType-value

Comment: Beware of the case of tagName.

Comment: @Casey: It will in an HTML page; in an XHTML page the case of the tag is preserved (so "a" will be "A" in HTML pages, and "a" in XHTML pages): http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Core-20001113/core.html#ID-104682815 (Assuming the XHTML page has been correctly served and not served as `text/html`.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder so it looks like the best option is `element.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'a'`

Comment: @Ped: Yes, or `element.nodeName.toLowerCase()` if it's possible that `element` won't actually be an element (e.g., if you haven't done the `nodeType == 1` check listed above). The `Node` interface has `nodeName`. For `Element` instances, it's the same as `tagName`. For other kinds of nodes, it's things like `"#text"` or `"#document"`. I think I'd always use the `nodeType` check, though.

Comment: 2019 update: at least on modern Chromium (v79.0.3945.79) the tagname string is uppercase.

_"For DOM trees which represent HTML documents, the returned tag name is always in the canonical upper-case form. For example, tagName called on a <div> element returns "DIV"_
[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName)

correct way to compare would be `node.tagName == 'DIV'`

Answer (score 6):

roenving is correct BUT you need to change the test to:

```
if(element.nodeType == 1) {
//code
}
```

because nodeType of 3 is actually a text node and nodeType of 1 is an HTML element. See http://www.w3schools.com/Dom/dom_nodetype.asp

Answer (score 4):

Although the previous answers work perfectly, I will just add another way where the elements can also be classified using the interface they have implemented.

Refer [W3 Org for available interfaces](https://www.w3.org/2003/01/dom2-javadoc/org/w3c/dom/html2/HTMLElement.html)

```js
console.log(document.querySelector("#anchorelem") instanceof HTMLAnchorElement);
console.log(document.querySelector("#divelem") instanceof HTMLDivElement);
console.log(document.querySelector("#buttonelem") instanceof HTMLButtonElement);
console.log(document.querySelector("#inputelem") instanceof HTMLInputElement);
```

```html
<a id="anchorelem" href="">Anchor element</a>
<div id="divelem">Div Element</div>
<button id="buttonelem">Button Element</button>
<br><input id="inputelem">
```

The interface check can be made in 2 ways as `elem instanceof HTMLAnchorElement` or `elem.constructor.name == "HTMLAnchorElement"`, both returns `true`

Answer (score 2):

I usually get it from the toString() return value. It works in differently accessed DOM elements:

```
var a = document.querySelector('a');

var img = document.createElement('img');

document.body.innerHTML += '<div id="newthing"></div>';
var div = document.getElementById('newthing');

Object.prototype.toString.call(a);    // "[object HTMLAnchorElement]"
Object.prototype.toString.call(img);  // "[object HTMLImageElement]"
Object.prototype.toString.call(div);  // "[object HTMLDivElement]"
```

Then the relevant piece:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(...).split(' ')[1].slice(0, -1);
```

It works in Chrome, FF, Opera, Edge, IE9+ (in older IE it return "[object Object]").

Answer (score 0):

## I have another way of testing the same.

```js
Element.prototype.typeof = "element";
var element = document.body; // any dom element
if (element && element.typeof == "element"){
   return true; 
   // this is a dom element
}
else{
  return false; 
  // this isn't a dom element
}
```

Comment: extending the prototype is usually a bad idea.