# Javascript IE6 getElementsByTagName not working

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6, getelementsbytagname

I've got this example page where I'm trying to put the wmode of every youtube element inside the page to "transparent".

To do it I need to get all the "object > params" and "embed" tags in the page.
The page I link you works like charm in all the browser except for IE6 (haven't cheked the other IEs yet).
With IE6 I can't catch the "params" since `document.getElementsByTagName('param')` returns an empty object, but this doesn't happen with the "embed"!
It won't work with `document.getElementsByTagName('object')` as well

Here is the page http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4064417/provaJs.html

Any suggestion why it's not returning just the "param" tags?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I have the same problem with IE 3.1 and the first netscape browser

Answer (score 1):

I recall some issue with `<param/>` tags and `getElementsByTagName`, but it's ages that I don't code in IE6. Instead of querying from `document`, trying to get the params calling `getElementsByTagName` from the `<object />` itself and see if it helps:

```
var objects = document.getElementsByTagName("object");

for (var i = 0, object; object = objects[i++];) {
    var params = object.getElementsByTagName("param");

    alert(params.length);
}
```

Comment: nothing to do =\
document.getElementsByTagName("object") returns nothing

Comment: I saw you have `<embed>` tag as well in the `<object>`, I remember IE6 had some issue to recognize `object` tag if you have node text inside it, maybe it could be the same with embed. Could you test if `getElementsByTagName` works if you have only `<param>` inside `<object>` and nothing more?

Comment: I can try, but I don't have control over the pages where my script will run on =\

Comment: I see, but at least you are able to understand the issue. If I'm correct, is a bug of IE6 and how it deal the `<object/>` tags in a totally different way from the regular DOM nodes. In that case, I'm afraid that if you don't have the control of the content of the pages you can't do much in IE6, for sure not in an elegant way. I remember we usually wrap `<object/>` tags in a `<div/>` exactly for this kind of issue, when IE6 was widely supported.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you would like to keep your app backwards compatible, but this exercise runs counter-intuitive to the general direction of the industry and its efforts to put IE6 down to rest (even [google has dropped support](http://lifehacker.com/5460043/google-apps-drops-support-for-ie6) for IE6).  Your time might be better invested if you focus on building a better web experience for pseudo-modern browsers instead of worrying about the legacy ones.

Food for thought - maybe use a browser detection script and encourage your users to upgrade so that they can experience your site in all of its modern glory :)

All that being said, ZER0's suggestion is dead-on.  Find the "object" tags in the page, and then iterate through its children until you find the tag you're looking for.  If you can't seem to grab the object tags with getElementsByTagName, you may very well have to iterate through the document.body.childNodes nodelist, checking for the [typeof(N) or N.NodeName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185034/testing-the-type-of-a-dom-element-in-javascript) along the way.

Comment: The customers of the company I work in wants services working on ALL browsers. My chief want me to make it work on IE6 as well and it's not my job to make him change his mind. Thank you for your answer though.

Comment: `for(var i = 0; i < document.body.childNodes.length; i++) alert(document.body.childNodes[i].nodeName);` skips the OBJECT elements

Comment: Part of your job as a developer is to be the subject matter professional that steps in and explains that sometimes the juice isn't worth the squeeze.  Your boss will love you for it.  You'll be saving him development time, man hours, and most importantly, money.  Think of all the time you're going to spend debugging IE6 every time you add a feature to your app -- is it really worth it to spend 50% of your hours debugging a browser used by less than 5% of the internet? (http://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php) How much time have you already lost to this one specific issue?

Comment: Are we talking about my job or how to solve an issue? Please stay on topic.

Answer (score 0):

If you must support browsers as old IE6, I would strongly recommend using a library such as jQuery rather than trying to access the DOM directly.

IE6 has a massive number of bugs and quirks that can break even the simplest and most innocuous of Javascript code. jQuery goes to great lengths to abstract these browser bugs and deficiencies away from the developer, allowing you to write code that works on all browsers.

For example rather than using `document.getElementsByTagName('object')`, you can use the jQuery code `$('object')`, which will give you the same end result, but will work around any bugs in whichever browser your end user is running.

jQuery does a whole lot more than just hide the browser bugs, of course, but if you're working with IE6, that alone is a good enough reason to use it.

(other libraries are of course available if you really don't like jQuery for some reason)

Comment: I tried jQuery('object') and the bug persists. I give up. There's no workaround. We will ask the client to fix the pages directly on the server.