# How do I change the style of all form elements when onFocus

Tags: javascript

I successfully finished a validation function for a form I have, when it catches an error I wish to remove the red borders on all the form elements when you click on any of them. I know how to call the function with onFocus but the problem is I do not know how to target the element and not the value of the element. this is the function I am having an error with:

```
   function clearFormErrors(x) {
        var element = document.forms[x].elements;
        for(i = 0; i = element.length; i++) {
            element[i].style.borderColor = "#000";
        }
    }
```

How do I target the input field and not the value inside to change the border to black?

Comment: test the node type. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185034/testing-the-type-of-a-dom-element-in-javascript

Comment: Inspect your for loop. In particular, "i = element.length" should most likely be: "i < element.length".

Comment: Yeah what Jo said would most likely explain an error.

Comment: Yep, you were right, I failed to see that. I tested it out and it works fine now. Thank you so much Jo, I appreciate it. How do I rate you for that answer? I am not so used to stackoverflow yet and would like to up a point for that.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, your loop should be <.

But if you only want to target "inputs", you should also check the nodeName.

```
   function clearFormErrors(x) {
        var element = document.forms[x].elements;
        for(i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
            if (element[i].nodeName.toLowerCase() == "input") {
                element[i].style.borderColor = "#000";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This case fails on some properly written doctypes. You should use `element[i].nodeName.toLowerCase() == "input"`

Comment: Thank you rob but I got it working how I wanted, thank you for the help.

Comment: i'd also declare a variable for the loop index, i.e. `for (var i = 0...`, to avoid contamination of the global scope or collisions with other loops in the function.

Comment: @Elton: your comment implies that you found an alternative solution of your own to address your problem; if so would you care to share that with us in order to offer useful information for future visitors with the same, or a similar, problem?

Comment: @avall Agree on the case issue (and updated above), and didn't intend for him to implement without thinking / improving. Just wanted to point out concept of what was missing. I'd do this very differently all together, but I don't know his requirements. :)