# AngularJS : Apply a directive only if element is a textarea

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wrote an attribute restricted Angular directive (`restrict:'a'`) that adds features to `textarea`. It makes no sense to apply it to any other type of element.

Adding a `if (element.nodeName == 'TEXTAREA') {` is really dirty and unreliable.

I tried to add `require: textarea` to it but it does not work and I get this error: `Error: No controller: textarea`

Question: Is there any cleaner way to properly apply this restriction?

EDIT: Additional constraint following the first answer.

I want to avoid using a template in this directive as I want to be able to use several directive of this type. Here is an example of what I'd like:

`<textarea splittable shared mergeable></textarea>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using your own directive (eg `my-textarea`) with `restrict: 'E', replace: true`, any additional attributes will get *carried over* to the root-element of the directive, even other attribute directives. So:

```
<my-textarea splittable class="foobar"></my-textarea>
```

could be rendered as:

```
<textarea splittable="" class="foobar"></textarea>
```

with `splittable` being executed.

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LMq3M/

So I think using your own directive is realy the cleanest way to handle this.

Comment: I think I'll create an element directive such as `advanced-textarea` that as a `textarea` template and that is required by my other directives.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion there is no need to add such controls as they just tend to add complex code when the real issue is human error.

Just document what the purpose and usage is for the directive.

Comment: This is truth! Only thing is I would like to have same attribute name that would implement same features but on different elements/logic, with different. Then I would have no way to do it. Example:

`<div mergeable></div>
<textarea mergeable></textarea>`

Comment: Then i understand your solution.
Your first solution is fine but you should also check on element.tagName as described here
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185034/testing-the-type-of-a-dom-element-in-javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185034/testing-the-type-of-a-dom-element-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

The idea is you give your directive a unique name, like myDirective and you can use it in HTML as such.

```
<body>
    <my-directive></my-directive>
</body>
```

The directive will replace the  tag with the template you provided in the directive controller. Which could be in your case a simple textarea element with added properties.

I recommend watching this video to clearly grasp the concept of directives. 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xoIHkM4KpHM

Comment: That is the solution I am currently using. The problem is that I will need to add several of these `textarea` specific directives (separate features to avoid spaghetti code).
I'll add this constraint to my answer. + have my upvote as your answer would otherwise be OK.