# How to tell the type of a JavaScript and/or jQueryobject

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebug, developer-tools

This question pertains as much to the ECMAScript language implementation we know as JavaScript as it does to jQuery and the developer tools availble in most popular browsers.

When you execute a statement like so:

```
var theElement = $('#theId').closest();
```

what is the *type* of `theElement`?

I assume that in a jQuery situation like above, many jQuery methods including the one above actually return the jQuery object itself, which packages the stuff you actually want to get to. This, so that it may maintain a fluent API and let you join method calls in a single statement like so:

```
$('#selector').foo().bar().gar().har();
```

However, in the case of jQuery then, how do you determine what the *real* underlying type is? For example, if the element returned was a table row with the Id tableRowNumber25, how do you get to that, say, using FireBug.

When I look at either a jQuery returned object or a simple JavaScript object in the watches window of Firebug or any of the Developer Tools in most popular browsers, I see a long laundry list of properties/keys and I don't know which one to look at. In a jQuery object, most of the properties are lamdas.

So, really, my question is -- how do you know the underlying type, how do you know what's *actually* being returned?

Comment: theElement is a jQuery Collection, to retrieve the raw html node do `var originalNode = theElement.get(0) // or theElement[0]`; You can use the firebug console to execute arbitrary code; One doesn't often know, but expect the return value type `:p`

Comment: And that would return a DOM element/node -- the type that is returned by `document.getElementById`, right?

Comment: Your welcome ! hmm I missed a change to get reputation points `:/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `theElement` will be `[object jQuery]`.

If you want the HTML element itself, you have to select it:

```
console.log(theElement[0]) //Return <div id='theId'>
console.log(theElement.get(0)) //Return <div id='theId'>
```

If you want the node name, there is a property in the HTML node element call `nodeName` wich return the capitalised node name:

```
console.log(theElement[0].nodeName)// Return DIV
```

Answer (score 1):

`typeof(jQueryElementList.get(0))` will return a string of the type.

Some browsers might return this as upper or lower case, I think. IE probably uppercases (see [Testing the type of a DOM element in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185034/testing-the-type-of-a-dom-element-in-javascript)). Apparently you can check the nodeType attribute (`jQueryElementList.get(0).nodeType`) to determine whether it is an html object/tag.